# is MathJax activated on Graphic Design?

Tags: discussion

simple question: is MathJax activated for Graphic Design?

I found an answer that I was thinking could use MathJax to show the fractions and didn't find it.

Maybe there isn't enough need for it here though, or maybe it is something that hasn't been brought up yet?

Just looking to see what the status is?

---

The Answer:  [Making a small ruler](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/33662/22559)

Comment: Which answer are you referring to?

Comment: not a whole lot of math, but if you guys do a lot with percentages or fractions, or equations in something like Photoshop or Gimp, then it might be worth it

Answer (score 3):

We do not have MathJax on GD.SE. I think it would be a difficult case to make to request the implementation on our site. It's pretty rare to come across a post that would greatly benefit from having it.

Comment: why can not mathjax be enabled for all of SE?

Comment: @joojaa because it is a "[heavy dependency](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60023/216955)"

Comment: I don't see any substantial proof of its heavyness. Maybe stack exchange is bandwidth congested? I don't necessarily think GD.SE needs it but just a general observation why good markup can not work everywhere.

Comment: @joojaa despite the requests for more details on what Jeff meant by that, I wasn't able to find any other official explanation. My guess is as good as yours